# How both text and image take place in a button

Tags: android, image, button, text

I tried to make a layout look like it

It looks like kinda button type.How can both text and image implement in button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Your Custom Button as:

**STEP 1:** Create a Button drawable shape xml in res/drawable/button_background.xml:

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”UTF-8″?>
<shape xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”>
<solid android:color=”#F000″/>
<stroke android:width=”1px” android:color=”#BB000000″ />
<padding
android:left=”10dp”
android:top=”7dp”
android:right=”10dp”
android:bottom=”7dp”
/>
<corners
android:bottomRightRadius=”5dp”
android:bottomLeftRadius=”5dp”
android:topLeftRadius=”5dp”
android:topRightRadius=”5dp”
/>
<gradient
android:angle=”90″
android:startColor=”#777″
android:centerColor=”#777″
android:endColor=”#BBB”
android:type=”linear”
/>

</shape>
```

**STEP 2:** add in your main Button xml layout as:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Facebook"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/leftimg"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/rightimg"
        android:padding="15dip"
       android:background="@drawable/button_background"/>
```

Comment: here `android:drawableRight="@drawable/rightimg"` doesnot make the image in fully right

Comment: @SidratulMuntaha : then remove padding android:right=”10dp” from layout

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in your button `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_icon"`

Comment: u mean i need to implement an image in its backgroung?

Comment: yes for right you can also give  android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"